# How can I import a long list of global variables (ex: %global_variable%) in an existing drawio diagram via a CSV?

Tags: diagram

I have an existing drawio diagram to which I want to add metadata (variables) that I can later use and refer to at shape level using "shape_property"=%gloabal_variable%

How can I import a long list of global variables and their corresponding values in an existing diagram?

Update: there seems to be a line just below the  line in the XML file that holds all these.
However I have no idea how to insert things there via a CSV import